# Is there a nice way to map a QStandardItemModel to many QLineEdits

Tags: c++, qt

I have a single value that needs to appear on several parts of my UI.

Where I have a list of values that is duplicated - for instance QComboboxes, I create a single QStandardItemModel and set that model on the combos.

I'd like to do something similar for this single value. Great, I thought, I'll use QDataWidgetMapper, but it turns out that QDataWidgetMapper doesn't allow one to many mappings, i.e. I can only map one widget to each column in my table. I'd like to map many.

I can think of a few roll-my-own ways around this but if there's an easy way to do it that is built in, I'd appreciate hearing it. I'm on Qt 4.7 fwiw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `QDataWidgetMapper` for each widget.

Alternatively, make one widget be the 'master value' and connect its `valueChanged()` signal (or whatever you want to call it) to the corresponding `setValue()` slot of all the 'slave' widgets.

Comment: Yes why I didn't think of just reusing the model and having a mapper per line edit, I don't know! Duh!